# Isotope add dynamically getSortData

Tags: jquery, arrays, wordpress, wordpress-theming, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to use isotope.js on my wordpress theme. 
I would sort the object in this way, where "Series,Music,Cultura,Sport" are "filter" generated by the custom taxonomy.

```
var $container = $j('.containerport');
                    $container.isotope({
                        stamp: '.stamp',
                        itemSelector: '.thumbportfolio',
                        getSortData : {
                            Series : function( $elem ) {
                                var isSeries = $j($elem).hasClass('Series');
                                return (!isSeries?' ':'');
                            },
                            Musica : function( $elem ) {
                                var isMusica = $j($elem).hasClass('Musica');
                                return (!isMusica?' ':'');
                            },
                            Cultura : function( $elem ) {
                                var isCultura = $j($elem).hasClass('Cultura');
                                return (!isCultura?' ':'');
                            },
                            Sport : function( $elem ) {
                                var isSport = $j($elem).hasClass('Sport');
                                return (!isSport?' ':'');
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

I would create a dynamic getSortData because if I add a new filter it should appear automatically without put hands inside the code. 
Is it possibile?
 Maybe with an array or a for cycle, but I don't know how to access to the list of the filter through jquery.
Thanks!

Comment: If you use a live debugger (F12 Chrome perhaps?) you can view the contents of the isotope object at runtime. It simply holds all the options passed (including `getSortData`) as properties of an options object on the instance of isotope (which you can obtain with something like `$j('containerport').data('isotope')`). When in doubt start digging into the source code of isotope a little as it can be very educational :)

Comment: I'm using firebug ;) But I can't find it, neither in the developer tools in Chrome :/ can you tell me where can I find it exactly? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the instance of isotope with `$('selector').data('isotope')`

e.g.

```
var isotope = $('selector').data('isotope');
```

in your specific case: `var isotope = $j('.containerport').data('isotope');` or `var isotope = $container.data('isotope');` as you have defined `$container`.

The options are stored on a property called... wait for it... options:

```
var options = isotope.options;
```

The getSortData object is purely a property of the options:

```
var sortData = options.getSortData;
```

You can simply add named elements using named properties like:

```
sortData.newSort = function($elem){ /* do something here*/ };
```

or indirectly like an dictionary using:

```
sortData["newSort"] = function($elem){ /* do something here*/ };
```

where "newSort" could also be a variable containing the property name:

```
var newSortVar = "nameOfPropertyToset";
sortData[newSortVar] = function($elem){ /* do something here*/ };
```

Here is a screenshot of the F12 Chrome debugger results for a watch variable that held `.data('isotope')` (taken from a random isotope JSFiddle):

[image]

If you need specific help after this, you will need to provide a JSFiddle with your own code.

Comment: I solved it in another way I found on internet with the creation of a function ;) thanks :)

Comment: @dborghez: If it answers your specific question, please post your own solution as an answer for others to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using this function :)

```
function (sorting) {
                            isotopeArguments.getSortData[sorting] = function (sorting) {
                                return function ($elem) {
                                    return $j($elem).hasClass(sorting) ? '' : ' ';
                                };
                            }(sorting);
                        }
```