# jQuery Isotope - dynamic objects for getSortData

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm working on an update of my website, using the *sorting* feature of [jQuery Isotope][1].

The problem is that my sorting links list **is dynamically generated by Wordpress**... I'd like to avoid editing the script each time a link is added or removed.

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t66L2qm6/1/

The sorting links are declared as recommanded by Isotope's doc:

```
$container.isotope({
  getSortData : {
    design : function( $elem ) {
      var isDesign = $elem.hasClass('design');
      return (!isDesign?' ':'');
    },
    architecture : function( $elem ) {
      var isArchitecture = $elem.hasClass('architecture');
      return (!isArchitecture?' ':'');
    }
  }
)};
```

So if I add e.g. a 'photography' link, I'll have to modify my JS code, what I want avoid to.

I'm losing all my hair over that matter... I read dozens of Google search resultats, without success... I found this Stackoverflow topic: [Isotope add dynamically getSortData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174725/isotope-add-dynamically-getsortdata)
but don't understand the solution nor can get it working.

I thought about doing a function which would create an object for each link found, called on getSortData:

```
function getLinks() {
  $('#main-nav').find('a').each(function() {
    var linkName = $(this).attr('data-option-value');
    // here output:
    linkName : function( $elem ) {
      var islinkName = $elem.hasClass('linkName');
      return (!islinkName?' ':'');
    }
  });
}

$container.isotope({
  getSortData : getLinks();
});
```

Don't know if I'm on a right track...
Any help would be so appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution, that I post here for whose would enconter the same problem:

Firsty we init Isotope on container DIV, without defining 'getSortData' option:

```
var $container = $('#container'), 
isotopeArguments = { 
  itemSelector: '.block',
  filter: '*',
  layoutMode: 'masonry',
  getSortData: { } 
};
```

Then, we create an array, where we put 'data-option-value' of each link found into '#sort-by' which is basically the nav div:

```
var arr = [];
$('#sort-by').find('a').each(function() {
  arr.push($(this).attr('data-option-value'));
});
```

Then, for each value of the array we write the correct markup into 'isotopeArguments':

```
$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    isotopeArguments.getSortData[value] = function (value) {
        return function (element) {
            return element.hasClass(value) ? '' : ' ';
        };
    }(value);
});
```

Finally, we relaunch Isotope:

```
$container.isotope(isotopeArguments);
```

Final code:

```
var $container = $('#container'), 
isotopeArguments = { 
  itemSelector: '.block',
  filter: '*',
  layoutMode: 'masonry',
  getSortData: { } 
};

var arr = [];
$('#sort-by').find('a').each(function() {
  arr.push($(this).attr('data-option-value'));
});

$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    isotopeArguments.getSortData[value] = function (value) {
        return function (element) {
            return element.hasClass(value) ? '' : ' ';
        };
    }(value);
});

$container.isotope(isotopeArguments);
```